# No routes matched location in react google authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to implement a google authentication with OAuth2.0 and passport into a MERN project but I got this Error:

```
No routes matched location "/user/auth/google"
```

this is my node server route handler to this location:

```
app.use('/user/auth/google', googleAuthRoutes);
```

this is my route file for authentication:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();
require('../authentication/passport');


router.get('/', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] }));

router.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/user/auth'
}));

module.exports = router;
```

this is my passport.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');
const passport = require('passport');
const OAuthUserModel = require('../models/OAuthUserModel')
const googleAuth = require('passport-google-oauth20');

dotenv.config();
const GoogleStrategy = googleAuth.Strategy;
const googleClientId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
const googleClientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const googleCallbackUrl = process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: googleClientId,
  clientSecret: googleClientSecret,
  callbackURL: googleCallbackUrl
},
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    UserModel.findOne({ id: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err) };
      if (user) {
        user.firstName = profile.name.givenName;
        user.lastName = profile.name.familyName;
        user.email = profile.emails[0].value;
        user.picture = profile.photos[0].value;
        return cb(null, user);
      } else {
        const newUser = new OAuthUserModel({
          firstName: profile.name.givenName,
          lastName: profile.name.familyName,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          picture: profile.photos[0].value,
        });
        newUser.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return cb(err);
          }
          return cb(null, newUser);
        });
      }
    })
  }));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

module.exports = passport;
```

and this is my loginform.js in frontend:

```
import { useLogin } from "../hooks/useLogin";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { UserSigninValidation } from '../validation/yupUserSchema.js';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const LoginForm = () => {
  const { login } = useLogin();
  const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
    await login(values.username, values.password);
    actions.resetForm();
  };
  
  const { values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    },
    validationSchema: UserSigninValidation,
    onSubmit
  });


  if (!isSubmitting) {
    return (
    <div className="signin-input">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          id="username"
          type="username"
          placeholder="username"
          value={values.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.username && touched.username ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.username && touched.username && <p className="error">{errors.username}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.password && touched.password ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.password && touched.password && <p className="error">{errors.password}</p>}
          
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
        <Link to={'/user/auth/signup'}>Don't have an account? Signup here!</Link>
        <Link to={'/user/auth/google'}>Google Authentication!</Link>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  }

  if (isSubmitting) {
    return (
      <div className="loading">
        <h1>Signing In</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default LoginForm;
```

and App.js if you need to look at:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/AuthContext';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import SignupForm from './pages/SignupForm';
import LoginForm from './pages/LoginForm';
import './App.css';
import { useContext } from 'react';

function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="pages">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={ user ? <Home/> : <Navigate to="user/auth/login" /> } />
            <Route path='user/auth/login' element={ !user ? <LoginForm/> : <Navigate to="/" /> } />
            <Route path='user/auth/signup' element={ !user ? <SignupForm/> : <Navigate to="/" /> } />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```